# iphone mapkit drag and get center location

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit, drag

HI,

I have a Mapview with some marker points + a marker for current location.

Now, what I want to do here is, when user drag or traverse through mapview, I want to find coordinate (latitude, longitude) of the new center location after map has been dragged.

I want to clarify once again, I am not talking about dragging the marker/point, I am talking about dragging the map with touch.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for `theMapView.region.center` or `theMapView.centerCoordinate` (should be the same) in your MapView's delegate `-mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` method.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this document:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

You can get that with the `centerPosition` property of your `MKMapView`. To tell when the location changes, implement the `-mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` method in your `MKMapViewDelegate`.