# ios Mapkit : fix annotation on middle of map

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am new in ios development. I have to create an application and requirement is that, fix the annotation point on the middle of map and then drag the map NOT the annotation to fetch the location. After dragging the map what ever be the location under that fixed annotation will have to fetch. A sample code or any link which cover this topic will be helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391660/iphone-mapkit-drag-and-get-center-location

Comment: thanx for your link its helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a class based on `UIView`, let's call it `CenterAnnotationView`.  Add your image to the center of the view for your annotation.

Create a `UIViewController` with a `MKMapView`, let's call it `MapViewController`.

Next, add `CenterAnnotationView` to `MapViewController` so it's over the entire `MKMapView`.  In `CenterAnnotationView`, add this code

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return NO;
}
```

This will allow touches to pass through to the `UIMapView`.

In `MapViewController` add the map delegate and implement

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
}
```

This will be called when the map has been dragged.  In this callback, find the center point and that should be directly underneath the annotation image.